# Change background of button created with shape

Tags: android, button, background, rounding

I created this shape and set it to the background of button to make around button but I can't change the background color of my button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    />
```

This is my button view and in the background I set the shape that I created but I can't change the color of the background

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>
```

Comment: `android:backgroundTint="#000000"` try this

Comment: and what have you tried to change this background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the color code. You can not use ee

Replace below line

```
<solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
```

with this

```
<solid android:color="#30ffffff" />
```

Alpha values(AA in #AARRGGBB) are used to control the transparency. Maximal value (255 dec, FF hex) means fully opaque. Minimum value (0 dec, 00 hex) means fully transparent. Values in between are semi-transparent, i.e. the color is mixed with the background color.

To get a fully transparent color set the alpha to zero. RR, GG and BB are irrelevant in this case because no color will be visible. This means #00FFFFFF ("transparent White"). To keep it simple one chooses black (#00000000) or white (#00FFFFFF) if the color does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are using White with transparency so that can not be easily visible so that may be happening.

Normally in Android color code in HEX and has a length of six, but you can also add two-digit of HEX as Prefix for set transparency.

> e.g color code : #FF0000 is red color and #80FF0000 is red color with 50% transparency.

For transparency Hex code use [You can get here more hex prefix code for % wise tranparrency](https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4)